# How to append to string using plistbuddy

Tags: bash, plistbuddy

plist has a field that I want to edit like

```
<string>$(STH)</string>
```

I want to append to it the $(STH)-sometext so it will be like something-sometext

Now the issue I have is plistbuddy doesn't like setting

```
PlistBuddy -c "Set someentryinplist $(STH)-sometext"
```

because bash says that the command is not found. Whats the correct way of appending a string in plist xml?

Comment: Using [XMLStarlet Command Line XML Toolkit: Download](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/download.php)

Comment: Ok so how to apply xmstarlet to <key>CFBundleName</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string> for example to append the string